# echo multiple $selected_value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sure this query is a straightforward one, but I couldn't seem to find an exact answer on the forum here.

I'm using the Simple Fields plugin for Wordpress, and just want to display all the answers from a particular field. This code below only displays the most recent entry:

```php
<?php $selected_value = simple_fields_get_post_value(get_the_id(), array(2, 2), true);
echo "$selected_value";
?>
```

I've tried the suggestions on the Simple Fields tutorial/documentation pages, but they seem to give me the same result - just the most recent entry, and not all the entries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look hier it is may be what you are looking for:

```
http://simple-fields.com/documentation/api/getting-values/simple_fields_fieldgroup/
```

Comment: I played around with some of the options here and on the other pages. That solution didn't quite work, but this seemed to do the trick: `<?php 
$field_value = simple_fields_values("location");
echo $field_value[0];
echo $field_value[1];
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use 'simple_fields_get_post_value':

```php
$selected_value = simple_fields_get_post_value(get_the_id(), 
                                               "Your Image Field Name", true); 

$theImageURL = wp_get_attachment_url($selected_value);

echo '<img src="'.$theImageURL.'">';
```

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. It's just a text field I want to display rather than images.